# I get syntax error in sqlalchemy but same works in sql server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The same SQL works fine in SQL management studio but when trying via Python using sqlalchemy I get;

```
ERROR: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '\ufeff'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [dbo].[backup-masterlist]([Customer Code],SiteCode ,SiteName ,[SIRA Freq],[Present in CX Addess Book] ,[SIRA Costs],[Invoice Cost Centre],[TTY]) SELECT 'AX0001',CAST([ri a] as varchar(50)),[Site Name],[SIRA Frequency Code],'TRUE',[SIRA Costs Code],[Cost Centre],[BM Territory code] FROM  [dbo].temptable as temp LEFT JOIN [dbo].[backup-masterlist] as mas on CAST(temp.[ri a] as varchar(50))= mas.SiteCode WHERE  mas.SiteCode IS NULL]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I'm executing the SQL query as follows;

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[backup-masterlist]([Customer Code]," + \
        "SiteCode ,SiteName ,[SIRA Freq],[Present in CX Addess Book] ,[SIRA Costs],[Invoice Cost Centre],[TTY]) " + \
        "SELECT 'AX0001',CAST([ri a] as varchar(50)),[Site Name],[SIRA Frequency Code],'TRUE',"+ \
        "[SIRA Costs Code],[Cost Centre],[BM Territory code]" + \
        " FROM  [dbo].temptable as temp " + \
        "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[backup-masterlist] as mas on CAST(temp.[ri a] as varchar(50))= mas.SiteCode " + \
        "WHERE  mas.SiteCode IS NULL"

        print(insert_query)
        with cnxn.connect() as con:
            con.execute(insert_query)
```

What is wrong with python/sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invisible unicode [`0xFEFF`](https://unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html) character in the beginning of your query:

```
insert_query = "INSERT
               ^^ Here
```

You have probably copied/pasted this string from somewhere else. Paste it into an online unicode inspector (such as [this](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect)) and you will see the issue yourself.

Just rewrite the first few characters manually and the problem should go away.